# Can you branch a yaml pipeline and trigger it only with commits to that branch, using the code in that branch

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, branch

I have a repo in Devops which has a yaml pipeline that builds a jar as an artifact. The trigger on this pipeline is set to master and the override YAML CI trigger setting is unticked in the GUI. I then branched this repo to make some changes. In the branch I changed the yaml files trigger to the new branch. I was expecting any commit to this branch to trigger the pipeline and build the jar based on the code in the branch. It doesn't trigger at all. I know I can manually trigger it to run on that branch but I thought this would work to automate it. Am I missing something fundamental with how pipelines work? Is this functionality even possible?

**YAML in master**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
```

Using this trigger in main does trigger the build on a commit to the repo.

**YAML in the branch**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - <nameOfBranch>
```

Using this trigger with the name of the branch does not trigger the yaml when a commit is made to the branch.

Comment: Your requirement is possible. And based on the phrased sharing, the pipeline should be triggered by the commits pushed to the `newBranch` since the **referenced YAML file** in **this** newBranch `include` `newBranch`.

Comment: Have you by any chance gone through the troubleshooting steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-filters-misconfigured-in-ci-and-pr-triggers)?Except for the UI overriding that you have ruled out, is there any `exclude` or `path` clauses that may affect this pipeline, has the pipeline `paused` or `disabled`?Perhaps you may share a screenshot with the **branch filter** in front of the .yml file and `trigger` section of the affected pipeline, when you `edit` this YAML pipeline.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Branched Repository?" are you referring to a Fork or a simply a branch in the repository.

Comment: @bryanbcook. In devops I've gone to my main repo, clicked the branch filter icon and clicked new branch.

Comment: Great. Terminology matters here. To clarify, you cloned the repository locally, switched to that branch, made your commits locally and then pushed them to the server? Or, could you let me know if you edited the files through the Azure DevOps user interface?

I'm also assuming that the pipeline that was created in the UI is linked to the YAML in question? There's no reason this shouldn't work, it does feel like you are missing something fundamental about how these are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice advantages of YAML-based pipelines is that they can version with the code, so it's possible to make changes to the pipeline and have them immediately applied.

To demonstrate:

1. Create a pipeline that is only triggered by changes in `main`. Commit the changes into a feature branch, eg `feature/trigger`. When you commit changes to this branch, by design the pipeline does not automatically queue.

   ```yaml
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - main

   pool:
     vmImage: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
   - script: exit 0
   ```
2. Merge `feature/trigger` into `main`. The pipeline should automatically queue.
3. Create a new branch, eg `feature/trigger-test` and modify the triggers to include your branch:

   ```yaml
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - main
       - feature/trigger-test
   ```

   Any commit to `feature/trigger-test` will automatically queue pipelines.

   [image: Automatically queued pipelines]

The exception for the above is scheduled triggers. Only the *default branch* setting for the pipeline controls the schedule.

Important notes:

- Case sensitivity. `feature/trigger` and `feature/Trigger` are different branches.
- Use the full path. `trigger` will not match `feature/trigger`
- Wildcards are supported `feature/*`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. In point 3, is this modifying the yaml file that exists in the master branch? In this scenario does any commit on the feature/trigger-test build the jar using the code in the feature branch or code in the master branch. Either way I can't see the benefit of doing it? If it builds the jar using code from master what is the point in triggering from the feature branch. If it builds code from the feature branch an untested jar will end up in the master artifacts directory.

Comment: My original question is more about the yaml file that exists in the branched repository. Is that yaml file essentially useless? Is there some sort of separation between a yaml file and a pipeline that I'm not understanding and that yaml file has no affect on an pipeline?

Comment: Yes, the changes to the yaml are in the `feature/trigger-test` branch, not `main`.  Changes that are committed and pushed to `feature/trigger-test` should trigger a CI build for that branch.